# Private certificate issue with chef server (knife ssl check - unable to get local issuer certificate)

Tags: nginx, openssl, ssl-certificate, chef-infra, knife

### I'm using open source chef12 server and I have created a private certificate for chef-server rather using self signed certificate. As i got error while using private certificate as below for "**knife ssl check**":

WARNING: There are invalid certificates in your trusted_certs_dir.
OpenSSL will not use the following certificates when verifying SSL connections:

### c:/Users/test/.chef/trusted_certs/server.test.com.crt: unable to get local issuer certificate

I followed steps given in "https://docs.chef.io/server_security.html" for private certificate adding server.crt and root.crt and configured the nginx server. But when i tried "**knife ssl fetch**" it downloaded server.crt and root.crt seperately in trusted_certs folder and getting the same error for "**knife ssl check**" again.

Please help me how to configure chef-server with private cert without error.

Comment: oh boy, certificate generation is not a one step process. And its hard to advise on where you messed up, which is why Chef is not willing to accept your cert. Best bet, is to retry by creating a new certificate